# I want intelliJ IDEA to inspect for duplicate tag ids in my seam xhtml files

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea, seam

Sometimes I get caught by duplicate IDs in my xhtml files.  It would save me some time if IntelliJ IDEA would alert me to these before I deploy my app.  Is there a way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you can run `Analyze` | `Inspect Code` with **Unresolved or duplicate ID** XML inspection enabled.

However, it would be more convenient to make it report the problem automatically on compilation/update, so I've submitted the [corresponding feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-78625), please vote.

Answer (score -1):

You could write a shellscript, that greps for all id=""s and counts them.

Or you could try to apply an XSLT.